# Python tkinter Radio Buttons "On Submit"

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button

in my code I do not understand how radio buttons are working. My problem is, that the radio-buttons variables are not passed further.

```
from tkinter import *

class SimpleDialog(Frame):
def __init__(self):

    super().__init__()
    self.output1 = ""

    self.output10 = ""
    self.output11 = ""
    self.output12 = ""
    self.initUI()

def initUI(self):
    self.master.title("New Input")
    self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
    
    frame1 = Frame(self)
    frame1.pack(fill=X)
    lbl1 = Label(frame1, text="Name:", width=20)
    lbl1.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=10)
    self.entry1 = Entry(frame1, textvariable=self.output1)
    self.entry1.insert(0,"Your name")
    self.entry1.pack(fill=X, padx=5, expand=True)  

    auswahl = IntVar()
    auswahl.set(0)

    frame10 = Frame(self)
    frame10.pack(fill=X)
    lbl10 = Label(frame10, text="Do you like tomatoes?", width=40)
    lbl10.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)   
    
    self.entry10 = Radiobutton(frame10, text="No",variable=auswahl, padx = 0, value=0).pack(anchor=W)        
    self.entry11 = Radiobutton(frame10, text="Sometimes",variable=auswahl,padx = 0, value=1).pack(anchor=W)
    self.entry12 = Radiobutton(frame10, text="Yes",variable=auswahl,padx = 0, value=2).pack(anchor=W)  
    
    frame3 = Frame(self)
    frame3.pack(fill=X)
    
    print(self.entry12)
    
    btn = Button(frame3, text="New entry", command=self.onSubmit)
    btn.pack(padx=5, pady=10)

def onSubmit(self):
    
    # Input
    self.output1 = self.entry1.get()
    # Radio-Buttons
    self.output10 = self.entry10
    self.output11 = self.entry11
    self.output12 = self.entry12
    self.quit()

def main():

# This part triggers the dialog
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("650x300+500+300")
    app = SimpleDialog()
    root.mainloop()

# Here we can act on the form components or
# better yet, copy the output to a new variable
    user_input = (app.output1, app.output10, app.output11, app.output12)
    try:
        root.destroy()
    except:
        pass
    return user_input

if __name__ == '__main__':
    diaginput = main()
```

Can you help me to change the code, so that I can get the values of the radio buttons, e.g. print(diaginput).

I have problems to get the values of the radio buttons.

Comment: Fix the indentation please

Comment: To get the values from the radio button, you should not use `self.entry10` or so, instead `auswahl.get()`. Yes, you will have to make it `self` to use it in a different function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not try to access the radiobuttons but the variable you used to store the values.
But you should make the variable an attribute of the class of your dialog to access it from all methods:

```
    self.auswahl = IntVar()
    self.auswahl.set(0)
    
    self.entry10 = Radiobutton(frame10, text="No",variable=self.auswahl, padx = 0, value=0).pack(anchor=W)        
    self.entry11 = Radiobutton(frame10, text="Sometimes",variable=self.auswahl,padx = 0, value=1).pack(anchor=W)
    self.entry12 = Radiobutton(frame10, text="Yes",variable=self.auswahl,padx = 0, value=2).pack(anchor=W)
```

In the function on submit, you may then just get the value of the `.auswahl` attribute

```
    # Radio-Buttons
    self.output = self.auswahl.get()
```

The variable `self.output` will then hold an integer with a value between 0 and 2, depending on your selection.

Comment: Should be *"value between 0 and 2"* instead.

Comment: So to avoid confusion, better to set the value to -1 than 0: `self.auswahl.set(-1)`. Or if nothing is selected, it will point it to 0.

Comment: @CoolCloud: That's why I assumed the values to go from 1 to 3 on the buttons. It's the rationale I also use when creating RBs. But probably it makes sense in the context to preselect one of the options.

Comment: Thank you for your help! It is working now. Additionally I had to add change self.output9 instead of self.output